# Automaticly copy images from site

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lets say a have two sites. "Site A" and "site B".

On site A there is a image that is updated daily.

I want to use this image on site B without linking to site A.

**How can I build a PHP script that automatically copies the image from A to B every day?**

The best would be if I could do this 100% on the server without involving visits, since site B might be a pure html site. Maybe this can be done using htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to *copy a file* with an `.htaccess` file.

What you should look into is a small PHP script that connects via FTP or SCP to your other server and then downloads your image locally.

Comment: How can I build a PHP script that runs every day, without a visit?

Comment: With a [cron task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (Assuming you using Linux as your operating system).